# How to embed formula.js from Github into html

Tags: javascript

im trying to use cumipmt function ( similar to the one from Excel) in my blogspot website and i need to embed an external javascript "formula.js" from "https://github.com/sutoiku/formula.js "to use the function cumipmt. I dont know how to embed it , can someone help?

Do i also have to embed "https://gist.github.com/ghalimi/4583240#file-cumipmt-js" too, in order to use cumipmt function?

This is what im calling,
document.calc.pay1.value = CUMIPMT(1.2, 100, 300000, 1, 100, 0);

Thanks

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
From comments from Br3t and atulquest93,
I placed the following code in a post under HTML instead of Compose but it still doenst work. Am i doing it correctly?

```
<!-- Numeric -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeric/1.2.6/numeric.min.js"></script>

<!-- Numeral.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>

<!-- jStat -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jstat/latest/jstat.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sutoiku/formula.js/master/dist/formula.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ghalimi/4583240/raw/d7e0a20cff288c52db9768f9291f380cf7c293a1/CUMIPMT.js"></script>


<script>
document.write(CUMIPMT(12/12, 10, 10000, 1, 10, 0));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sutoiku/formula.js/master/dist/formula.min.js"> </script>
```

or copy the content and include the content directly

```
<script>
 --content--
</script>
```

call this function after including the js ..

```
document.calc.pay1.value = CUMIPMT(1.2, 100, 300000, 1, 100, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks , can seem to work..not sure where im going wrong

Answer (score 0):

At first, at your blogspot-dashboard go to **Design** and click **Add gadget** at any area (preffer to do this in footer. Choose **HTML/JavaScript**-gadget and insert into content

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sutoiku/formula.js/master/dist/formula.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ghalimi/4583240/raw/d7e0a20cff288c52db9768f9291f380cf7c293a1/CUMIPMT.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.calc.pay1.value = CUMIPMT(1.2, 100, 300000, 1, 100, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of going Design, Add gadget, HTML/JavaScript, can i do it directly in a post under 'HTML' instead of ' Compose'.

Comment: Let's look from the other side. For use this you should connect patched formula.js and all it's dependencies. What `CUMIPMT` does calculate? If you use constant values for it is it always return same result?